# How to append key and value after implementing prefetch_related() method

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have implemented a class based view with a `GET` method to get payslip details per `id`. How do I append the `net_allowance` in the payslip `object` so that JSON would look like this:

```
{
    "employee__user__id": 2,
    "payslip_no": "GGT5698",
    "employee__user__first_name": "Nick",
    "basic_salary__salary_value": 80000.0,
    "net_allowances": 5400.0,
    "total_deductions": 2500.0,
    "payment_mode__name": "Bank",
    "month_ending": "2018-03-16",
    "employee__user__last_name": "Cannon"
}



class PayrollView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        try:

            payslip = Payslip.objects.filter(id=pk).prefetch_related('user', 'employee').values(
                'payment_mode__name', 'payslip_no', 'allowances__amount', 'deductions__amount', 'month_ending', 'basic_salary__salary_value', 'employee__user__last_name', 'employee__user__first_name', 'employee__user__id'
            )

            net_allowance = payslip.aggregate(
                net_allowance=Sum('allowances__amount'))
        except Exception as e:
            # print(e)
            return Response(data=e, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        return Response(data=payslip, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
payslip = Payslip.objects.filter(id=pk).prefetch_related('user', 'employee')
result = payslip.aggregate(
    net_allowance=Sum('allowances__amount')).values(
    'payment_mode__name', 'payslip_no', 'allowances__amount','deductions__amount', 'month_ending', 'basic_salary__salary_value',
    'employee__user__last_name', 'employee__user__first_name', 
    'employee__user__id','net_allowance' 
)
```

Comment: I am got a TypeError('values() takes no arguments (10 given)',) is not JSON serializable log. Then I removed .values() added it after prefetch_related() method in payslip object. I only see the net_allowances but the rest of the JSON data is not visible

Comment: I think you need `annotate` instead of `aggregate`

Answer (score 0):

Used `.annotate()` instead of `.aggregate()`

```
 payslip = Payslip.objects.filter(
            id=pk).prefetch_related('user', 'employee').values(
            'payment_mode__name', 'payslip_no', 'allowance_types', 'deduction_types', 'month_ending', 'basic_salary__salary_value',
            'employee__user__last_name', 'employee__user__first_name',
            'employee__user__id'
        ).annotate(
            net_allowance=Sum('allowances__amount'))
```